# How do I copy an array into another array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm

I am just starting out learning assembly and I am having a hard time understanding how I would copy one array into another array.

for example, let's say I have 2 arrays J and K:

J and K both contain 5 elements which are numbers that are 8 bits wide.

```
J = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
K = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

J is located in register 1 and K is located in register 2

How would I go about "appending"/"copying" J to K? (If that is even the correct way to think about it)

Would it just be:

```
LDR R3, R1[0] ; placing 0th J element into register R3
MOV R2, R3 ; Moving the R3 element into the array K
....
....
....
```

Continue like that until all elements have been copied over to array K

So the result I am trying to obtain is an array with the elements from both the initial arrays result = `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I am sure this is completely wrong, so if anyone is able to shed some light on this for me it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You would need a `STR` to write into memory. Since you say you have 8 bits wide items, you should use `LDRB` and `STRB`. Also you will need to make sure you have enough space in the array and obviously write elements at the proper addresses.

Comment: Arrays have fixed sizes, unless you mean that there's spare space before `K` that you aren't actually counting as part of the initial 5 elements.  In C terms, think about what `memcpy(K, J, 5)` would do, for `uint8_t J[5], K[5];`

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely be done in assembly, but it's difficult for a few reasons:

1. You need to know where the arrays are, and make sure you don't overwrite anything important when trying to copy them. Let's say for example that you want to just copy K directly behind J. If something else important is stored behind J then it will get erased!
2. How big is each array? It's obvious to you and me but the computer doesn't really have a clue. You have two choices: measure it yourself or know the array sizes ahead of time.
3. You'll need a different routine for each data type.

For this example code I'll assume that you want to place the appended array J+K in a separate section of memory that isn't going to overwrite anything you're using. Also this code assumes that both array sizes are 5 bytes. This isn't particularly useful since chances are you're going to want your code to be able to handle arrays of various sizes, not just this one particular size.

```
    LDR R2,=ARRAY_J
    LDR R3,=ARRAY_K
    LDR R4,=ARRAY_L

    MOV R1,#5         @ size of ARRAY_J goes here.

loop_append_J:
    LDRB R0,[R2],#1    @ load R0 from ARRAY_J, add 1 to the pointer so we read the 
                       @ next byte on the next pass.

    STRB R0,[R4],#1    @ store R0 into ARRAY_L (ARRAY J + ARRAY K), add 1 to the 
                       @ pointer

    SUBS R1,R1,#1      @ decrease loop counter and set the flags accordingly
    BNE loop_append_J  @ if R1 doesn't equal zero, loop again.

    MOV R1,#5          @ size of ARRAY_K goes here

loop_append_K:
    LDRB R0,[R3],#1    @ this is pretty much the same story, just with the second 
                       @ array. R4 already points to where it needs to.
 
    STRB R0,[R4],#1
    SUBS R1,R1,#1
    BNE loop_append_K

@ now your program is done, do whatever you need to do to return, be it BX LR or whatever

.data                 @ forgive me if the syntax is wrong, I'm used to VASM which doesn't 
                      @ have data directives like this.
ARRAY_J: 
   .byte 0,1,2,3,4    @whatever directive you use to define 8-bit values
ARRAY_K:
   .byte 5,6,7,8,9    @whatever directive you use to define 8-bit values

  
ARRAY_L:              @empty space to hold the new array.
   .space 64,0        @this is more than enough room to store the new array.
```